# Put word by word in paragraphs

Tags: python, file, dictionary

How can I put an output a `text.txt` file so that it is sorted as follows:

> "This is a way
>
> that has a little text
>
> for it to be placed
>
> where every word
>
> be in a paragraph."

Comment: so are you saying you want each word on a separate line?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Typically you will get the best results if you also share what you've tried, and what about your attempt isn't working.

Comment: That text is not sorted in any obvious way as far as I can tell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is helpful for the community if you provide some more details of the attempts you've made so far. Please review the guidelines here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this to get the individual words on their own lines

```
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for l in f:
        line = l.replace('\n', '')
        for item in line.split(' '):
            print(item)
```